# iOs Safari : Photo preview gives wrong orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, orientation, mobile-safari

I'm using **CSS** `background-image` to preview taken photos. *(not `<img src="">`)*

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image"></div>
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" accept="image/*">
<label for="upload">Upload</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**JS :**

```
function readImage(el) {
    if (el.files && el.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var base64 = e.target.result;
            $('.image').css('background-image', 'url(' + base64 + ')');
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(el.files[0]);
    }
}

$('#upload').change(function() {
        readImage(this);
});
```

When photo taken, the preview gives wrong orientation on **mobile Safari**. Any know how to fix ? Any trick ?

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/015oek13/